# Редирект с главной страницы на внутреннюю

Tags: laravel, redirect, php

Добрый день. Не могу сделать редирект с главной страницы на внутреннюю. MVC - Laravel 4. Пытался сделать через

```
Route::get('/', ['as'=>'index', 'uses'=>'PagesController@index']);
```

, не получается. Также были попытки сделать через .htaccess.

Comment: @Profik, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

`Route::get()` не редирект производит, а указывает по какому маршруту отправить запрос - в какой контроллер/action. Реализация редиректа в php иная:

```
header('Location: http://site.com/pages/');
exit;
```

, либо [Laravel средствами](https://laravel.ru/docs/v4/responses#%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Упрощённый пример:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return Redirect::action('PagesController@index');
    /*
       // либо нативно:
       header('Location: http://site.com/pages/');
       exit;
    */
});
```

Через серверные настройки:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index\.php)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /pages/ [R=301, L]
```

Данное условие удовлетворяет следующим URL-ам: `http://site.com/index.php` и `http://site.com/`

Результатом будет редирект на `http://site.com/pages/`

Можно [проверить здесь](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

Comment: Через .htaccess - ошибка 500. Выкладываю содержимое файла.

---
<Files .htpasswd>
   deny from all
</Files>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
 
 Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index\.php)?$ [NC]
    RewriteRule . /express/ [R=301, L]
   
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: > Но правильно всё же будет через серверные настройки:

Редиректами приложения должно заниматься само приложение. Девопс должен иметь возможность развернуть приложение, устроив только редирект на index.php.

Comment: @Profik Уберите  всё лишнее. Оставьте только:

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index\.php)?$ [NC]
    RewriteRule . /express/ [R=301, L]
    
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

У Вас реврайты когда-нибудь работали? Может быть `mod_rewrite` не установлен. 

    sudo a2enmod rewrite
    sudo service apache2 restart

Проверить установлен или нет:

    sudo apache2ctl -M | grep "rewrite_module"

Comment: @Etki, скорее всего, Вы правы. Для меня достаточно указать белые список для assets и всё.

@Profik, используйте редирект на уровне бизнес-логики (см. выше).